# How to have the project ready and accessible with different states?

Tags: git

We are in prototyping and pre-production of our next project and I have to change the code base drastically each day and usually we need to get to different versions that we want.

I'm using Git but I don't know it's inside out. First I thought of go to specific commits so the code base would be like that version but then I may need to continue it so I was thinking forking and branching but reading the documentations, I was not sure that it would solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you've not given us much to go on, and one has to wonder why you would need to change the codebase that drastically if you're nearing pre-production?

but, it sounds like you need to use [branches](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).  This way you could have concurrent versions of the codebase in the same repository.

I would say however, that if the changes between the 'versions' are that significant, you probably aught to have a separate repository for each one.